# Counting integers in a consecutive sequence where least prime factor is greater than $3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I am attempting to count the number of integers with a [least prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html) greater than $3$ in a sequence of consecutive integers.

For example, if I count the number of integers in $10,11,12,13,14,15$, the number is $2$ since $\{11,13\}$ have a least prime factor greater than $3$.

I feel that my argument is too long and can be improved.  I would appreciate any suggestions for making it more concise, more precise, or more standard.

Let $p_n > 3$ be the $n$th prime, $m>0$ be an integer.

Claim:  $\left(\sum\limits_{m < x < m + p_n \text{ and } \text{lpf}(x) > 3} 1\right)\ge n-2$

Argument:

(1)  If $m=1$, there are clearly $n$ primes between $1$ and $(1+p_n)$ and $n-2$ are greater than $3$.

(2)  For $m=6i+1$, this is clearly true based on (1) since for every $1 < x < (1+p_n)$ where lpf$(x) > 3$, $6i+1 < x+6i < (6i+1 + p_n)$ and lpf$(6i+x) > 3$

(3)  For $m=6i+2, m=6i+3, m=6i+4$, it is true from (2) since $6i+2, 6i+3, 6i+4$ all have least prime factor $\le 3$.  So that there are $n-2$ integers where lpf$(x+6i) > 3$, $6i+4 < x + 6i < (6i+1+p_n)$

(4)  For $m=6i$, this is true for $n-3$ integers based $6i+1 < x+6i < (6i+p_n)$ and it is true for $n-2$ integers since $6i < 6i+1$ and lpf($6i+1) > 3$

(5)  For $m=6i+5$, there are $n-3$ integers between $6i+5 < x+6i < (6i+p_n+1)$.  If $p_n = 6j+1$, then lpf$(6i+p_n+4) > 3$.  If $p_n=6j+5$, then lpf$(6i+p_n+2) > 3$.  Either way, there are $n-2$ integers $6i+5 < x+6i < (6i+p_n+5)$

Comment: How is the sequence supplied to you?  Is it a list of numbers?  A formula for the $n^{th}$ number?  An arithmetic progression?  Numbers starting from somewhere and increasing by $1$?  You seem to be assuming something in your work, but I can't tell what.

Comment: I am assuming this is true of any sequence of consecutive integers: $m+1, m+2, \dots, m+ p_n$. Do you see a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: It is far too complicated.  Every third number has a factor $3$ and among $3n+1$ and $3n+2$ one is even.  There are no consecutive pairs of integers with smallest prime factor greater than $3$. The only ones are of the form $6n+1$ and $6n+5$

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I have updated my question.  I hope it is now clearer.  In the example you give, I would only count $6n+1$ and $6n+5$.  My goal is to count the number of integers $x$ where $m < x < m+p_n$  and that have a least prime factor greater than $3$.

Comment: I read the title that the integers with least factor greater than $3$  must be consecutive.

Comment: Yes, the title was incorrect.  I sometimes mix up words without realizing it.  I should have caught that before hitting submit.  Thanks very much for your comment!  :-)

Comment: The least prime factor of an integer $N>1$ is greater than $3$ if and only if $\gcd(N,6)=1$. So, you just have to exclude the numbers divisible by $2$ or by $3$ (or both). The inclusion-exclusion-method, for example allows to count these numbers.

Comment: @RossMillikan Still easier One of the numbers $n$ and $n+1$ is even and therefore has prime factor $2$, so for $n\ge 2$, no pair $(n,n+1)$ with smallest prime factor greater than $3$ can exist.